# When using Unity RegisterType with a name the Interceptor doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-container, interception

```
container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyType>("MyType");

container.AddNewExtension<Interception>()
            .Configure<Interception>()
            .SetInterceptorFor<IMyType>(new InterfaceInterceptor());
```

When I Resolve my Type with a name,the Interception doesn't work.
But when I remove the name,it will works again.
what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify which *InterceptionBehavior* you want to use. Setting up the interceptor does not add any behavior.

Have a look at the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660911%28PandP.20%29.aspx).

The section *Unity 2.0 Approach* contains a sample config.

Comment: The sample shows how to Implement interceptor Manually.But I want to do it automataicly like my code.I use the Attribute to define the Behavior.

Comment: @Dozer Then give a complete sample of your code so I don't have to guess what you are doing.